# I want to link vb.net and mysql but i do not know how when sql.data is not appearing to my vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to link vb.net and MySQL.i have successfully downloaded mysql. I have opened a vb.net program so that I can link with MySQL but I can't find mysql.data for the 2 to link. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Nuget Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution
In the Manage Packages window select Browse in the left upper corner. Type MySql in the Search box directly below. Choose MySql.Data. On the left side of the Manager select Install. Now you can add `Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient` to the top of your code file and you are good to go.